# I want to get only session id value from this array field

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Can I get this sessionid from this array field?

```
var data =  ['JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9; Path=/sample/; 
Secure; HttpOnly']
```

Comment: Post the code that you have attempted.

Comment: Have you tried doing a split on the ';' to get the parts of the string?

Comment: get Array value at index 0, split it by ; and get the first value. split by = get index 1.

Comment: `data[0].split(/[=;]/g)[1]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value of `JSESSIONID`, split on `;` and `=` (if it's always first):

```js
var data = ['JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9; Path=/sample/; Secure; HttpOnly'];
const [, sessionId] = data[0].split(";")[0].split("=");
console.log(sessionId);
```

Comment: how do i get JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9  this thing

Comment: @susmithapanda you just need to split by ";".

Answer (score 2):

Use split method:

```js
var data =  ['JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9;Path=/sample/;Secure; HttpOnly']
var item = data[0].split("=");
var sessionId = item[1].split(";");
console.log(sessionId[0]);
```

`sessionId[0]` having your desired field i.e sessionid.

Now,If you wants `JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9` then you just need to `split(";")` then you can able to get that field.

```js
var data =  ['JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9;Path=/sample/;Secure; HttpOnly']
var item = data[0].split(";");
console.log(item[0])
```

So item[0] gave the this result (`JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9`)

Comment: This will return `CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9;Path`.

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.split` is unnecessarily expensive (as it reads through the entire string and allocates+copies new strings into a new array), whereas `indexOf` with `substring` is better for simpler operations like this:

```
let d = data[0];
let startIdx = d.indexOf( 'JSESSIONID=' );
if( startIdx == -1 ) throw "not found";l
let endIdx = d.indexOf( ';', startIdx + 11 );
let sessionId = d.substring( startIdx + 11, endIdx );
```

Comment: Even RegEx `split()` [doesn't seem](https://jsperf.com/parse-string-split-vs-nosplit/1) to work that much slower and I doubt that task is worth 5 lines of code, where you can simply do `split(/[=;]/g)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

If your `JSESSIONID` key may appear anywhere within the string:

```js
const data =  ['JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9; Path=/sample/; Secure; HttpOnly'];

const res = data[0]
  .split('; ')
  .map(item => item.split('='))
  .find(item => item[0] == 'JSESSIONID')[1];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

this code seems faster than `split()` function

```
var data = ['JSESSIONID=CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9;Path=/sample/;Secure; HttpOnly'];

var dataItem = data[0];
var eqIndex = dataItem.indexOf("=");
var scIndex = dataItem.indexOf(";", eqIndex+1);
var sessionId = dataItem.substring(eqIndex+1, scIndex);
```

#### output:

```
CE04D3A4F9A930F7716ABD1CF1D7E4A9
```

---

#### benchmark:

http://jsben.ch/rkGwP

[image: benchmark]